# Rails API :select DESC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, select, console

i had a quick question about TmdbMovie.find code

Say i search for :title => "Harry Potter", all i can really do is add a limit to how many it saves, so Say there are 7 Harry Potter movies, and I just want the first 3, what code could i add so that it only saves the returned movies ( limit => 3) by their release date

So i've tried these but they dont work, :order => "released DESC", :released => "DESC" and many more, how can i do this ? save movies in an order: release date DESC

Hi There,

I am using the Ruby-TMDB Gem to add movies to my rails app. 
TO find info on a movie I run this command in the console

```
TmdbMovie.find(:title => "Harry Potter", :limit => 3)
```

but I only want the three FIRST Harry Potter Movies! 
So how can i have this code only return the first three movies, based on their release date
so :order => "released DESC"? This code doesnt work and i have tried others

PS: My Column for a release date is `release_date` and TMDB's column is `released`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this gem uses Structs to manage its data. keep that in mind... this isn't ActiveRecord querying but their API makes it look like it is AR.

However it looks like the gem has an **[API](https://github.com/aarongough/ruby-tmdb#tmdbmoviebrowsequery_optionslanguage-expand_results)** for browsing the data.

Instead of **.find** use **.browse** and it looks like it'll work for you.

Comment: I have considered using **browse** but since I then use @movie.each to save the returned movies when **find**, i get an error (using **browse**)

Comment: yeah. I think that's a shortfall of the gem. It looks like you can either use the find __or__ the browse. :( I think you'll have to drop to ruby for the ordering. i.e [@movie.sort!(&:title)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21)

Comment: It doesnt work, I am using this code to create the returned Movies.


`@movie.each do |movie| 
Movie.create(title: movie.name, description: movie.overview) 
end `

Comment: you don't really need to sort that if you're recreating it in your database because you'll be able to use AR ordering when you fetch those. It might be failing because you need to pass your arguments as a hash i.e. title: {movie.name, description: movie.overview}. I can't remember if it forces them into a hash.